# Why inseting unicode character in python -c throw exception

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unicode

if I type this into python console

```
>>> ord(u'⚤')
```

it work but when I try to put it into `python -c` from bash

```
python -c "print ord(u'⚤')"
```

it throws:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    print ord(u'⚤')
                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: I thought it might be because your bash doesn't support unicode, but when I tried it in my terminal, I got this error instead (which is more what I'd expect when bash doesn't support unicode): `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found`

Comment: Interesting -- although I get a different error:  `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found`, when I echo it into `junk.py` and try to run that file:  `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file junk.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`

Comment: Granted, in my case it might actually be a terminal problem rather than a bash problem.

Comment: I got the same error, but when run in python: command >>> print ord(u'⚤')    then got result: 9892

Comment: Does this work for you? `python -c "print (u'⚤')"`

Comment: @NateC-K this work from bash `user@server:~$  echo ⚤`

Comment: It's surely terminal issue, when running in bash > python -c 'print u"%c" % 9892' it returns:
⚤

Comment: > python -c "print (u'⚤')"
â¤

Comment: @NateC-K HaHa I know what the problem was, when you type ⚤ in bash it overlaping on next character so `'⚤'` look like this `'⚤` and `'⚤'.` look like this `'⚤.` when I copy what I typed it show `python -c "print ('⚤'')"` but display as `python -c "print ('⚤')"` so it look like correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, when you type ⚤ in bash it overlaping on next character so `'⚤'` look like this `'⚤` and `'⚤'.` look like this `'⚤.` when I copy what I typed it show `python -c "print ('⚤'')"` but display as `python -c "print ('⚤')"` so it look like correct code.

So my code look like this in terminal

```
python -c "print ord(u'⚤)"
```

but code that I run was like this

```
python -c "print ord(u'⚤')"
```

because I copied that character from other place in my terminal and I select by accedent 2 characters the one I wanted and the one that was overlaping.

Comment: So this was really a problem with how your terminal displays the character?